# jQuery fade in fade out image opacity animation

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to find a way to have a simple image being displayed that automatically fades in fades out (opacity 0 > 100) in a constant loop.

Are there any way to achieve this in jQuery without necessarily having to rely on a flash solution?

Some info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('img').on("hasFadedOut", fadeInImg);
    $('img').on("hasFadedIn", fadeOutImg);
    fadeOutImg();
})

fadeInImg = function () {
    $('img').fadeIn(500, function () { $('img').trigger("hasFadedIn"); });
};

fadeOutImg = function () {
    $('img').fadeOut(2000, function () { $('img').trigger("hasFadedOut"); });
};
```

Comment: this is a great method , thank you very much for it! quick question: How could I (eventually) have this changed to just work on a fadeIn method? Meaning it should start with nothing and then slowly fade in the image.

Comment: you can set img opacity to 0 using css or juqery: $('img').css({ opacity: 0 }) and then use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method. Or simply set img display to none and rely on fadeIn method. Is it what you asked for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){

        $('#image').fadeIn('slow', function() {  
            $('#image').fadeOut('slow');
        });

     }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#image').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // After Animation complete.
    $('#image').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information - I reckon this works on a click fashion. Would there be a way to have this automatic, without any button. I simply just require 1 image that have on my landing page to fade in fade out.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my scenario. I have a 'group cost calculator' on one of my websites. Each time a visitor adds some item, and the cost is over $0.00, they have the option to 'download/print' the estimate. I wanted them to notice the 'print' icon that displays automatically. The icon hides if the cost returns to $0.00. I have a loop set up so the visitor does not get annoyed, also because it annoyed me while testing :) You can set the loop for any number, or remove the marked lines to have it flash continuously. Questions?

Start with your image, add the ID so it can be controlled.. I added the 'cursor:pointer' so visitors would know it was 'clickable'.

```
<img id="est_print" src="est_print.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Print Estimate" alt="" />
```

Add the timer variables just above your 'flash_icons' function..

```
var fi1; // set outside the 'flash_icons' function so other functions can stop the flashing
var fi2;
```

Your main function, which I put outside my 'Document Ready' function.

```
function flash_icons() {
    $('#est_print').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var loop = 0; // remove to keep flashing
        $('#est_print').css('opacity', '1');
        fi1 = window.setInterval(function(){
            $("#est_print").animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
            fi2 = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#est_print").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 600);
                loop++; // remove to keep flashing
            }, 2000);
            if (loop == 4) { clearTimeout(fi2); clearInterval(fi1);} // remove to keep flashing
        }, 2200);
    }, 2000);
}
```

To start the flashing..

```
flash_icons();
```

To stop the flashing via some other function..

```
clearTimeout(fi2);
clearInterval(fi1);
```

I am using jquery-1.7.js, and tested it on XP/Win7/Win10, browsers back to IE8/FF ESR v52. I did not test it on Chrome. Works perfect.